# Embed Post in external page

Tags: embed, iframe

I want to create a page that can be embedded in other sites with an embed script like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/the_hidden_page?setting=set1&setting2=set2"></iframe>
```

The page will need to be 'hidden' so it does not appear in the menu on my site and it will need to accept a query string.

The URL in my example does not need to be exactly like this, something like `/the_hidden_page/set1/set2` would be fine as well.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Actually, that is not true. I did try generating the embed code through an AJAX call. However, even though I used nopriv, it would not work if the user was not actually logged into the site. So I decided that may not be the best approach.

Comment: How do you output your menu?

Comment: I am just using the 20-11 theme. I am not really familiar with what it does. However, I would rather not modify the theme if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisite: Custom Plugin

First you'll need a small plugin. Just copypaste it into a `.php` file, add it to some folder, zip and upload it to your installation an you're done.

### What it does

This small plugin only checks if the `wpembed` query part is present and if it is set to `true`. If both is the case and the request looks like for example

```
https://example.com?wpembed=true
```

then a custom template will be searched first in your child theme in your parent theme and, if found, will be used instead of any other template from the template hierarchy.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#102480) WP Embed */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_102480_wpembed' );
function wpse_102480_wpembed()
{
    if ( isset( $_GET['wpembed'] AND 'true' === $_GET['wpembed'] )
    {
        include( locate_template( 'wpembed.php' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

### In your (child) theme

Just add another template file to your (child) theme named (in this example) `wpembed.php`. There you add whatever you want to be output when it is called. You can access query args via `$_GET` parameters or (maybe) even via `get_query_var( 'key_name' );`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks perfect. I will not be able to try it out until tomorrow, and I will come back to accept. 2 quick questions; 1 - This will work even if the user is not logged in? 2- when I write the template PHP, it will be able to access all the normal WP variables such as $wpdb?

Comment: Ad 1) Yes, unless you cover parts with `is_user_logged_in()`. Ad 2) Yes, it loads WP core as normal.

Comment: I have an non-WP question. Why did you use 'true' === $_GET['wpembed'] instead $_GET['wpembed'] == true?

Comment: The first version `'true' === $_GET['foo']` is a "Yoda" condition with a `strict` check. A Yoda condition avoids the mistake that you only use one `=` mark and accidentally _assign_ the value to the `$_GET`-variable. The `strict` (three `===`) forces PHP to not only check the value, but the _type_ (string, int, etc.) as well. This brings PHP closer to a type safe language (like C for example), is faster and avoids having typecasting and such non sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can add or remove pages from the menu as per your requirement. If you haven't created a menu yet, create one in Appearence->Menus and then set that as primary menu and then add all the pages that you want to display in the menu section.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, as stated in the title of my message, I need a page that DOES NOT appear in the menu.

Comment: you simply create a menu and don't add that page in the menu section, so it will not appear in the menu section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I created a new menu, which did not show-up anywhere on the site, which is good, and I added my page to it. HOwever the page still showed up in the main menu. I set the parent to NO PARENT.

Comment: Once you created a new menu, select the menu as the primary menu. You will get in the theme locations block. you will see primary menu written there and a dropdown along with it. in teh drop down select the menu you want to display in the front end

Comment: definitely, as suvajit says, use the Appearence->Menus. You will build the main menu (as well as others if you need to), adding the pages you want to show in your site.

And you simply DON'T add the pages you DON'T want to see in the menus.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen

http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

...and related...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Exclude Pages from Navigation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages/) by Simon Wheatley. Edit your page and uncheck the box *Include this page in lists of pages* in section *Exclude Pages*. Save page. That's all.

Comment: This is to exclude your page from results of wp_list_pages functions which is used by twentyeleven theme to build a menu.

Comment: To properly handle GET parameters and show the content create custom template page-_your-page-id_.php. The name of this template is significant as it will be used automatically ( no special checks neccessary ).